# How to get local language in IE-11

Tags: internet-explorer, localization, angular8

I am trying to get the local language in Angular in IE-11.

I set the local language in the IE-11 browser as french and then trying to get the local language from IE-11 as follows.

```
this.lang = window.navigator.languages ? window.navigator.languages[0] : null;
    this.lang = this.lang || window.navigator.language || window.navigator['browserLanguage'] || window.navigator['userLanguage'];
```

it is working fine for all browser but for IE-11 I am not getting the correct local language. it is returning me en-US every time.

can anyone help me with this how to get the correct local for IE-11 in Angular8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you set your browser local language in Control Panel like below in win 7?

[image]

In this situation, we can get local language in IE 11 using `window.navigator.browserLanguage` which is "fr-FR". In other modern browsers, we can only use `window.navigator.language`:

[image]

In your app, you could use the code below:

```
var sAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
var Idx = sAgent.indexOf("Trident");
//check if IE 11
if (Idx > 0) { 
   this.lang = window.navigator.browserLanguage;
}
else {
    this.lang = window.navigator.language;
}
```

Comment: I am on windows 7

Comment: In morden browsers, there's only `window.navigator.language`. In IE 11, you could use `window.navigator.browserLanguage` to get local language. Please see my edit.